# Selenium - get first level child by class name

Tags: java, selenium

I use Java Selenium 2.0. This is my HTML element, it contains comments and reply comments:

```
<div class="comment-list">
    <div class="comment">
       <a class="content">Comment 1</a>
       <div class="reply-comment">
           <div class="comment">
               <a class="content">Comment 1.1</a>
           </div>
           <div class="comment">
               <a class="content">Comment 1.2</a>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="comment">
        <a class="content">Comment 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I select contents within comments but without reply comments?
This is the expected result:

```
- Comment 1
- Comment 2
```

Note: I don't want to use absolute css selector such as:

```
 comment-list > comment > content
```

Solved! This is my solution:

```
// Mark reply comments with a class "is-reply-comment"
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
List<WebElement> replyCommentElements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".reply-comment .comment"));
for (WebElement replyCommentElement : replyCommentElements) {
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].className += ' is-reply-comment'", replyCommentElement);
}
// Find comments except comments were marked "is-reply-comment"
List<WebElement> parentCommentElements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".comment:not(.is-reply-comment)")
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use an absolute CSS selector? That would solve this problem.

Comment: @PhuLuong is your issue solved?

Comment: Sorry. I miss stackoverflow for a long time. I don't want to use an absolute CSS selector because in fact, my html structures are usually changed, plus it's not a beautiful solution. I found my solution and noted below my question. Thank all

Answer (score 1):

You can use the XPath

```
//div[not(@class='reply-comment')]/div/a[@class='content']
```

but that's really not that much different than the CSS selector

```
div.comment-list > div.comment > a.content
```

but the CSS selector is faster, has better browser support, and is more consistently implemented between browsers than XPath.

Comment: have a look at the question. @PhuLuong specified that he didn't want to use `absolute css selector`. Even more, he wrote it down.

Comment: @nazar_art Yep, he did... that's why I posted the XPath. My point is that the XPath that solves this problem does so in pretty much the same way a CSS selector would. It's not really an absolute CSS selector... whatever that is... it doesn't start at the HTML tag. It just specifies a few levels of the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like XPath for such kind of selection will be a little bit long.

However, it is possible to achieve with `not()` and `contains()`:

> //a[@class='content' and not(contains(text(), '.'))]/text()

it selects exactly what you need:

[image]

**BTW** your `<a>` elements don't have closed tag `</a>`.

**UPDATE:**

I saw your comment and at this case I can suggest only following solution:

> //div[@class='comment-list']/div/a[@class='content']/text()

Selection is still correct in this case.

Comment: Thanks nazar_art. It's an ideal but my reply comments doesn't always contain dot (.) character.

Comment: @PhuLuong you need to add this info to your question. I updated my answer as well for this.